# hide div for some times even after reload the page jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a div which appear after one third scrolling on the page. There is a close button inside that. By clicking the close button, div will be disappear for next 10 minutes (for testing purpose, lets time is 5 seconds) even after reloading the page. I can't write jQuery properly for this.

Here is the [fiddle of my work](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/bz2snmwo/9/). Main issue is after reloading the page, if I suddenly scroll after clicking on close button, hidden div is appeared without waiting for 5 seconds.

```js
var closeOnce;
var hide = localStorage.getItem('hide');
    
function showDiv() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('body').height() / 5) {
    $('#banner-message').slideDown();       
  } 
};

function countDown() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    closeOnce = false;
    showDiv();
  }, 5000);
};

$('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
  $('#banner-message').slideUp();
  closeOnce = true;
  localStorage.setItem('hide', 'true');
  countDown();
});

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if(!hide) {
    if (!closeOnce) {
      showDiv()
    }
  } else {
    countDown();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.instruction {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="instruction">
  <h1>Scroll down to appear a div</h1>
</div>

<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button class="close">close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using cookies, you could install the [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) and set one with the current timestamp when the close button is clicked:

```
$('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
  $.cookie('closed', new Date().getTime());
});
```

Then on scroll you check the difference between the current time and the time the button was clicked (if any)

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var closeTime = $.cookie('closed');
  if (closeTime) {
    var diff = new Date().getTime() - closeTime;
    if (diff > 10 * 60 * 1000) {
      $.removeCookie('closed');
      // show div
    }
  }
});
```

I should note that you don't need this plugin to set/read/delete cookies, but since you're using jQuery anyway this is the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are over complicating things, and setTimeout won't remember the time after you refresh the page, it will just restart the timer, so you need to set localStorage on hidden time and compare with current time on scroll:

https://jsfiddle.net/vzatgnrm/9/

```js
//scroll function
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  //compare differene between hidden and current time, 5 seconds or if hidden time is null
  if(new Date().getTime() - localStorage.getItem("hiddenTime") > 5000 || localStorage.getItem("hiddenTime") == null) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('body').height() / 5) {
      $('#banner-message').slideDown();
    }
  }
});

//close button click
$('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
  $('#banner-message').slideUp();

  //set closed time to storage
  localStorage.setItem("hiddenTime", new Date().getTime())
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.instruction {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="instruction">
  <h1>Scroll down to appear a div</h1>
</div>

<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button class="close">close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.